# WSO2 IOS Profile time out during install

Tags: wso2

I have WSO2 EMM version 1.1.0 set up. I have the certs all working and everything is playing nicely. I compiled the IOS client and have it installed on my phone via OTA. I am in the process of registering my device. I have a user setup and I have the proper password. I can successfully login from the registration page on my phone and I get the profile downloaded and it has the green "Verified" message on the profile. The problem occurs when I press the install button on the profile. I get a activity spinner at the top of the screen and it says "Installing Profile". It spins for about 30-60 seconds and then I get a message stating "Profile Installation Failed. The request timed out". Any ideas on what would be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to {emm_home}/repository/conf/emm-config.xml and chehck whether the following entries are properly pointed to your server.

```
<iOSEnrollURL>https://10.10.10.174:9443/emm/scep</iOSEnrollURL>
<iOSProfileURL>https://10.10.10.174:9443/emm/profile</iOSProfileURL>
<iOSCheckinURL>https://10.10.10.174:9443/emm/checkin</iOSCheckinURL>
<iOSServerURL>https://10.10.10.174:9443/emm/server</iOSServerURL>

<!-- post url for device tokens -->
<TokenURL>http://10.10.10.174:9763/emm/api/devices/iostokenregister</TokenURL>
```

Comment: I looked at the firewall and I had port 9673 instead of 9763 open. But now I am getting this error in the wso2carbon.log.  Error occurred in PKIMessage Unrecoverable CA private key Cannot recover key (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#155)

Comment: I was able to fix the cert problem. Had to change the password and all is good now.